# Displaying image in 500 status page (Django)

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-500

I have a Django app with nginx as a reverse proxy web server. I want to serve an image in my 500 error page. How do I do that within a Django project?

---

I tried the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28882843/4936905). I.e. my virtual host file for nginx contains:

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
    root /home/myuser/myproject/myapp/templates/;
}

location = /500.png {
    root /home/myuser/myproject/myapp/static/img/;
}
```

Note that 500.png is indeed placed at `/home/myuser/myproject/myapp/static/img/500.png`.The HTML template refers to the 500 error image like so:

```
<img src="500.png" alt=".">
```

But, although the 500 error page loads correctly, the image itself never loads, falling back to `alt` in the `img` tag. What could I be doing wrong? Please ask for more information in case you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to load a 500.png image on the current dir.

Change to:

```
<img src="/500.png" alt=".">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'img/500.png' %}" alt=".">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailing slash in the img url,

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html { root /home/myuser/myproject/myapp/templates; 
            } 
    location = /500.png { root /home/myuser/myproject/myapp/static/img; 
            }
```